# Translate locates from en to other languages automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, yaml

I want to translate my all locale files in my rails application from `english` to other languages, i don't want to do it manually, i tried to use google API but that is taking long time to convert their content. Is there any library or gem that can help me to convert.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

No need for a Google solution we have a rails one:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n(github) and  https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-i18n/versions/4.0.8(ruby gem) 
Put the gem in the gemfile bundle it and all the local yaml files for many different languages will be automatically in your app once you restart your server.